# python matplotlib gives wrong corners of border

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are two examples of plots created with matplotlib (both from matplotlib webpage):

[The first one](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/xcorr_demo.pdf) (right). [The second one](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended_00.pdf) (wrong).

The corners of the border in the second one (when highly magnified) are missing a tiny piece. The line ends where is center of the perpendicular line, not where is the further edge.

[image]

However, even when I use the source code for the image which is right on web:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.randn(2, 100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.xcorr(x, y, usevlines=True, maxlags=50, normed=True, lw=2)
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
ax2.acorr(x, usevlines=True, normed=True, maxlags=50, lw=2)
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

I get wrong result. Why is it so? Some bug in my version of matplotlib/python? Something else?

I use python 3.4.3 and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I add [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uNWdt.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but rather it is due to the default [`capstyle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_capstyle) used for the axes spines. The `capstyle` defines how a line is terminated and therefore how it looks when two lines come together.

You can set the `capstyle` to be `butt` (default), `round` or `projecting`. You can alter this by calling `spines.set_capstyle` for each of the axes spines.

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_capstyle('projecting')
```

For your specific version of matplotlib (1.3), it looks like that is when they changed the default `capstyle` for patch objects to be `butt` but there was not a way to set the capstyle of the `spines` as there is in the current version:

> For Patch, the capstyle used is now butt, to be consistent with the default for most other objects, and to avoid problems with non-solid linestyle appearing solid when using a large linewidth. Previously, Patch used capstyle='projecting'.

Comment: seems like this should be an `rcParam`, but I can't find any relevant options

Comment: @tom Maybe `lines.dash_capstyle`?

Comment: no, that will be for dashed `line2D` objects, I suspect

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I tried to use it, I got 'Spine' object has no attribute 'set_capstyle' What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @fales `ax` is just an example variable name. In your case you would use `ax1` or `ax2` instead...

Comment: @fales Hmmm doesn't appear to exist in the version you are using. Any particular reason you have to use version 1.3?

Comment: @Suever Just the one, that it is included in my Linux Mint distribution. Hopefully I will be able to upgrade it.

Comment: @fales I'll look into this a little more and let you know if I figure something out. Also for what it's worth in newer versions, the spines themselves *should* default to 'projecting'